# android application development

Tags: android

whenever I run an android application there comes the emulator but it does not show the output. 
At runtime this warning is showed.

```
[2012-02-18 10:31:15 - Emulator] Warning: No DNS servers found

the console part shows the following messages
2012-02-18 11:26:52 - LunchList ------------------------------
2012-02-18 11:26:52 - LunchList Android Launch!
2012-02-18 11:26:52 - LunchList adb is running normally.
2012-02-18 11:26:53 - LunchList Performing apt.tutorial.LunchList activity launch
2012-02-18 11:26:53 - LunchList Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'secondAVD'
2012-02-18 11:26:53 - LunchList Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'secondAVD'
2012-02-18 11:27:15 - Emulator emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
2012-02-18 11:27:16 - LunchList New emulator found: emulator-5554
2012-02-18 11:27:16 - LunchList Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
2012-02-18 11:29:15 - LunchList emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'apt.tutorial.LunchList activity launch'!
```

Answer (score 1):

Close your eclipse and AVD both and start again everything will be fine.

Comment: i have made another AVD with less API level that is 14 but when i run the app there comes the emulator with the Android animated label.. nothing more although i waited a lot but when i see the eclipse window there was error messages in the console window that are [2012-02-19 21:17:39 - Emulator] NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument
[2012-02-19 21:17:42 - Emulator] savevm: unable to load section nand_dev
[2012-02-19 21:18:57 - LunchList] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'apt.tutorial.LunchList activity launch'!

Comment: THANKS ALLAH it worked now..... i made a new AVD with API level 10 and with Google API and when i run the project it showed the output...

Answer (score 0):

try to run in your command prompt:

adb kill-server
adb start-server

this is to restart the Android Debug Bridge.
If you have any problem running the command above, try to check if adb in in your path environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove BackCamera and Snapshot from Emulator, it worked for me.