# Android emulator on Toshiba

Tags: android, android-emulator

I try to run the SoftKeyboard example to make sure all my installation work fine, including the emulator. It seems the build to be fine except that the emulator seems stuck at Android initialization and no keyboard come out. I picked randomly Nexus as my device. The message is

```
[2014-04-20 18:01:57 - SoftKeyboard] Performing sync
[2014-04-20 18:01:58 - SoftKeyboard] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with    compatible AVD 'AVD_Nexus'
[2014-04-20 18:01:58 - SoftKeyboard] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_Nexus'
[2014-04-20 18:02:50 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2014-04-20 18:02:50 - Emulator] 
[2014-04-20 18:02:50 - SoftKeyboard] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-04-20 18:02:50 - SoftKeyboard] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-04-20 18:17:37 - SoftKeyboard] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2014-04-20 18:17:37 - SoftKeyboard] Device API version is 19 (Android 4.4.2)
[2014-04-20 18:17:37 - SoftKeyboard] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-04-20 18:17:37 - SoftKeyboard] Uploading SoftKeyboard.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-04-20 18:17:37 - SoftKeyboard] Installing SoftKeyboard.apk...
[2014-04-20 18:20:16 - SoftKeyboard] Failed to install SoftKeyboard.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
```

What does this message mean? What device should be used?

Comment: is this the full error log?

Comment: Yes, this is the full message log.

Comment: you should look at or share with us the logcat log which prints out the actual log messages.

Comment: Sorry, where is logcat log located?

Comment: which IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse, come with the SDK

Comment: Ok, so it's the tab next to Console which is at the bottom of the screen. What you shared is from Console. You need to look at LogCat to debug android.

Comment: Hmm...What is the name of the Tab? The tabs left/right to the Console are Declaration and Call Hierarchy. Nothing under these two tags though. Is there a way to access the LogCat from the menu? Yes, I copied from the Console tag.

Comment: LogCat. Goto Window-> Show View -> Other -> Android-> Logcat.

Comment: ah, very cool, I found it. But it is empty for all categories (debug, info, etc) even there is no filter is put on. While waiting and testing, I changed to a mid resolution device. Now I got this from the Console: NAND: nand_dev_load_disk_state ftruncate failed: Invalid argument. The error remains even I closed/reopened Eclipse like other posts suggested.

Comment: This post said API level 10 had no NAND problem. I am using Level 19(Android 4.4.3). Similar problem seen on Level 19? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9339227/android-application-developement